# Xamarin: Hide the button if condition is false

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Xamarin Forms.

I want to know how to hide a button if a specific condition is false.

ex: I need to hide the submit button until the text field has a value.
(if the text field is null, cannot click the submit button)

this is my .xaml code

```
<Entry Grid.Row="0" 
        Margin="10,10,10,20"
        x:Name="ground_area"
        Grid.Column="1" 
        MaxLength="5"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Placeholder="area"
        FontSize="18"/>

<Button x:Name="avg_nut" 
    Text="Submit"
            Grid.Row="5"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Margin="40,0,20,50"
            Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" 
            Clicked="submit_click">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers):

```
<Entry x:Name="ground_area"/>
<Button Text="Submit">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding Text.Length, Source={Reference ground_area}, FallbackValue=0}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="False"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Also, check `IsEnabled` property, it's better than hiding the control.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I ll try with IsEnabled property too.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can use the property of the button `IsEnabled="{Binding booleanProperty}"` and in your view model you can manipulate the value of this property depending in what you want

I recommended you to use View Model instead of Code Behind is not that hard learn how works MVVM (Model View ViewModel)

That's my advice.

I hope this can solve your problem